# Struggling with Atom Zombie Smasher - any suggestions?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

I'm loving Atom Zombie Smasher, but I don't seem to be very good at it!

In fact, I'm really struggling to even rescue the minimum amount of people, so I was wondering if the community had any tips and tricks they would like to share with all the other smashers out there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each campaign is going to vary for you based on the randomness of the game itself, but the following are a few suggestions to hopefully help you out.

In the early stages of the game try to kill **all** zombies before the sun goes down. This will conquer the territory and give you points at the end of each round for the rest of the game. Capturing territories early on is definitely the most important thing.

Early on upgrade the helicopters return time rather than the speed that it picks up civilians. Its already relatively fast (about .24 seconds initially) so you want to make sure your helicopter will drop off and get back as fast as possible to pick up more civilians. Do this for at least the first 3 levels of the helicopter.

If you're finding the stages too difficult use the minus key to slow the game down. This can help in the beginning to give you some thinking time.

For a few of the different units of the game here's a few strategies I like to use.

**Infantry**
Start them off covering one side of the zombie entrances, and fall back to your main landing area over time picking off zombies as you go. In my opinion this is the most important unit in the game. They are really good for cleaning up any stragglers. I like to throw a point or two in accuracy first and then work on their speed.

**Snipers** 
I try to position these units so they can cover one set of the zombie entrances. Then move their target location closer to the helipad as time goes on, you can get pretty good coverage if you place them in one of the corners of the map and target the opposite side.

**Detonation Charges**
I put these a few blocks ahead of where the zombies are coming out (2-3), this maximizes amount of zombies that will be killed. I make sure they are all lined up with each other vertically, since you have to set them off all at once.

If your still finding the game too difficult don't be afraid to turn some of the mods on, like `Triplets`, or `Chooser`. Triplets allows you to have more than one of each type of mercenaries, and Chooser allows you to choose which mercenary are on each months lineup.

Comment: so there is no range penlty on the snipers?

thanks for all the infomation by the way.

Comment: @TrewTzu Im not really sure if there is, I haven't noticed one. They have a pretty slow firing speed though so  if they are covering 2-3 zombie entrances alot of the zombies will still get through. They are just good for thinning them out.

Comment: i had a few trys last night and your suggestions help a lot! thanks!

also i had a few goes and i dont think the snipers are effected by range, and they can more or less fully hold down two Zed enterances by them selfs

Comment: @TrewTzu Awesome glad the information helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The cannon is good as well if you can get the timing right.  I had one game where I covered 1 entrance with land mines and was covering the other two with the cannon, had 2 shots, and surprised myself by killing them all so I won the territory.  The cannon is great for both groups of zombies or trying to protect fleeing humans.  I would target near the back of the group of humans which would hit the front of the pack of zombies and maybe kill a couple of humans, but better than having the infection spread like crazy in the pack of humans.